# Pyspark dataframe column calculations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am learning to use Pyspark dataframes for some projects and had a question regarding building a result set. Below is a grid representing second by second information of users logged into a SaaS platform. This is obviously derived from user login and logout data which I am successfully able to do using DF.

The 1st column represents seconds value in an hour, the 2nd column represents total number of users loggedin, 3rd represents new user who logged In at that given second, 4th shows Users who logged out.

For ex: in the 100th second, total 1 user was logged in and hence In = 1, Out = 0
In 105th second, 10 new users logged in and thus total = 12 and In = 10
In 107th second, 11 existing users logged out and thus Out = 11 and total = 1

```
SecondsInHour total       In  Out
100           1           1   0
101           1           0   0
102           1           0   0
103           2           1   0
104           2           0   0
105           12          10  0
106           12          0   0
107           1           0   11
```

....

My attempt to derive this result looks like this:

```
df.groupBy('logged_seconds') \
  .agg({'logged_seconds':'count', 'login_offset':'count', 'logout_offset':'count'}) \
  .show()
```

which is not correct. How do I get the above results?
Thanks

**Updated to add code:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, explode, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType

def seconds_range(start_date,end_date):
    start_seconds = start_date.minute * 60 + start_date.second
    end_seconds = end_date.minute * 60 + end_date.second
    return list(range(start_seconds, end_seconds+1))

def to_seconds(date):
    return date.minute * 60 + date.second

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('MyApp').master('local[2]').getOrCreate()

# register udf function with spark
seconds_range_udf = udf(seconds_range, ArrayType(IntegerType()))
to_seconds_udf = udf(to_seconds, IntegerType())

# create dataframe with sample data.
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('user1', '2019-12-01 9:02:00', '2019-12-01 09:04:00'),\
    ('user2', '2019-12-01 9:02:30', '2019-12-01 09:04:00'),\
    ('user3', '2019-12-01 9:03:23', '2019-12-01 09:03:50')],\
    ['user', 'login_start_dt', 'login_end_dt'])

# assign data types to the columns
df1 = df1.select(df1.iqcckey,\
    to_timestamp(df1.login_start_dt , 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').alias('login_start_dt '),\
    to_timestamp(df1.login_end_dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').alias('login_end_dt'))

# construct a new column that is an array of seconds logged in.
df2 = df1.\
    withColumn('login_offset', to_seconds_udf('login_start_dt ')).\
    withColumn('logout_offset', to_seconds_udf('login_end_dt')).\
    withColumn('arr_logged_seconds', seconds_range_udf('login_start_dt ', 'login_end_dt'))

# convert the 3rd column (array) into rows
df2 = df2.withColumn('logged_seconds', explode(df2.arr_logged_seconds))

# group, count data
df2.groupBy('user','logged_seconds').agg({'logged_seconds':'count', 'login_offset':'count', 'logout_offset':'count'}).show()

print('End program')
```

Comment: What is the 'df' that you are using? Or what is the raw data that you have? You are showing output desired, but what is the input?

Comment: Can someone help me out?

Comment: do you have already have the Secondsinhour, total columns, and from those do you want to get a solution of the In , out columns?

Comment: @Mohammad. Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Building your dataframe:

Added more data to verify.

```
data=  [[100,1],
        [101,1],  
        [102,1],
        [103,2],
        [104,2],
        [105,12],
        [106,12],
        [107,1],
        [108,2],
        [109,12],
        [110,2],
        [111,0],
        [112,22],
        [113,17],
        [114,20]]
columns= ['SecondsInHour','Total']
df= spark.createDataFrame(data,columns)
df.show()

+-------------+-----+
|SecondsInHour|Total|
+-------------+-----+
|          100|    1|
|          101|    1|
|          102|    1|
|          103|    2|
|          104|    2|
|          105|   12|
|          106|   12|
|          107|    1|
|          108|    2|
|          109|   12|
|          110|    2|
|          111|    0|
|          112|   22|
|          113|   17|
|          114|   20|
+-------------+-----+
```

## Defining windows and clearing out null for first value:

Basically subtracting from lag, and using positive value for one column, and negative for the other, and then handling the first value for each.

```
w2= Window().orderBy(df.SecondsInHour)
df.withColumn("lagdiff",(F.col("Total")- F.lag("Total").over(w2)))\
.withColumn("lagdiff2", F.col("Total")- F.lag("Total").over(w2))\
.withColumn("lagdiff3", F.when((F.col("lagdiff2")>0),F.lit(0)).otherwise(F.col("lagdiff2")*-1))\
.withColumn("lagdiff4", F.when((F.col("lagdiff") <0), F.lit(0)).otherwise(F.col("lagdiff")))\
.withColumn("In", F.when(F.col("lagdiff").isNull(), F.col("Total")).otherwise(F.col("lagdiff4")))\
.withColumn("Out",F.when(F.col("lagdiff3").isNull(), F.lit(0)).otherwise(F.col("lagdiff3")))\
.orderBy(df.SecondsInHour.asc())\
.drop("lagdiff","lagdiff2","lagdiff3","lagdiff4").show()

+-------------+-----+---+---+
|SecondsInHour|Total| In|Out|
+-------------+-----+---+---+
|          100|    1|  1|  0|
|          101|    1|  0|  0|
|          102|    1|  0|  0|
|          103|    2|  1|  0|
|          104|    2|  0|  0|
|          105|   12| 10|  0|
|          106|   12|  0|  0|
|          107|    1|  0| 11|
|          108|    2|  1|  0|
|          109|   12| 10|  0|
|          110|    2|  0| 10|
|          111|    0|  0|  2|
|          112|   22| 22|  0|
|          113|   17|  0|  5|
|          114|   20|  3|  0|
+-------------+-----+---+---+
```

Comment: I fixed it and added more data to test it. it works well. let me know what you think. @NetRocks

Comment: Yes, it works. Just trying to understand the logic. What is the difference between lagdiff and logdiff2? Also, I get a warning about partition not being defined for Window Operation. I think I need to define a default one.

Comment: for the window partition warning, in your real data you should have a hour column, as you have a seconds in hour column, so that hour column could be the partition for the window.

Comment: the lagdiff and lagdiff2 calculate the same lag difference however, for in, I am filtering out all non-negative values, and converting leftover negative values to positive for use, and for out, i am filtering out all negative values and using positive ones. basically getting both in,out from same logic but diff filter.

Comment: after which , this logic provides null at the start, so I use the first value in seconds in hour for the first in value, and 0 as the first out value. the starting condition can be changed as required but the other logic should work for all cases